# Checking a range of RedHat versions in Korn shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, redhat, ksh

I have a **Korn shell** script and the following piece of code works:

```
if [ $LINUXVER = 7.2 ] || [ $LINUXVER = 7.3 ]; then
```

But I want to modify the code to make a range that covers `7.2`, `7.3`, `7.4`, etc. I know I need to use something like `[0-9]`, and I have tried a number of things, but nothing works. This script is running on multiple remote servers and not the local server where the script is located.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of ksh are you using? Use 'print ${.sh.version}'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a relatively recent ksh (ksh93 or a compatible clone) then you can use double parentheses for mathematical expressions. For instance

```
testver() {
   if (( LINUXVER <= 7.1 || LINUXVER >= 7.4 )); then
      print "Unsupported version $LINUXVER"
   else
      print "Supported version $LINUXVER"
   fi
}

LINUXVER=6.9
testver
LINUXVER=7.2
testver
LINUXVER=8.0
testver
```

The output of this script is

```
Unsupported version 6.9
Supported version 7.2
Unsupported version 8.0
```